# Groovy equivalent for ruby all and none

Tags: ruby, collections, groovy, conditional-statements

I want to know if all (or none) of the items of a Collection in Groovy satisfy certain condition.

I know that in ruby (and in c# with linq), you can call methods like `all?` and `none?` and pass the condition as a closure to accomplish this.

Is there an equivalent for this methods in Groovy?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, its `!any` (for Ruby's `none`) and `every` (for Ruby's `all`):

```
def list = [1, 2]
assert !list.any { it < 0 }
assert list.every { it > 0 }
```

See also documentation at http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections